# How can I make my android app not openable after a particular period of time?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im currently trying to implement a feature like Whatsapp which shows a custom activity on not updating whatsapp for a particular period of time.

I searched on stackoverflow and found a similar kind of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035000/how-to-make-an-android-app-expire-after-a-fixed-amount-of-time). But the code provided seems to be not working. Any Possible codes to suit this?

This is what i have tried so far

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final long CLOSE_APP = 432000000;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
       PackageInfo pi= null;
       try {
        pi = pm.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
       } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
       long publishTimeInMilli = pi.firstInstallTime;

      long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
      if(now - publishTimeInMilli) > CLOSE_APP) {

         finishAffinity();
      }
 }
```

and this code

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = 
  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  if (!prefs.getBoolean("firstRun", true) {
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     c.setTime(new Date());
     c.add(Calendar.DATE, 5);  // number of days to add
     String date = sdf.format(c.getTime());  // dt is now the new date
     editor.putBoolean("firstRun", true);
     editor.putString("valid_until", date).apply();
  }
  else if(new Date().after(sdf.parse(prefs.getString("valid_until","")))) {
    finishAffinity();
  }
```

On using this code I was getting an error *incompatible types: required boolean found long.*

Comment: You should tell us on which line you got the "incompatible types" error

Comment: on if(now - publishTimeInMilli) > CLOSE_APP)

Comment: That line is missing a `(`.

Comment: got this error on runtime Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this method. I wrote little programm, launched it and all worked good))
After 30 days your programm will close after launching

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static int demodays = 0;
public static int finishdate = 0;
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (demodays == 0){
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("D");
        String data = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        demodays = Integer.parseInt(data);
        finishdate = demodays + 30;

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("data", demodays);
        editor.putInt("finishdata", finishdate);
        editor.apply();
    }

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("D");
    String today = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    int today1 = Integer.parseInt(today);

    if (today1 == finishdate) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Period of trial has finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        this.finish();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences). You can save the current version as well as the date this version was first found into your Shared Preferences and just compare them to the actual values. If your version increases, you can update those values. If not, you can then calculate from them, how long the old version was installed. Hope this is what you wanted to know.

Comment: I tried using Shared Preferences but didnt worked. could you please tell me whats the problem. I have edited my code

Answer (score 0):

you can set timer and run that in background, use service for this and while this service is running, user tries to open your app then just call finish method. finish method automatically destroys your activity, so that will not allow user to open ur app.once timer finishes you can allow user to open it.

Answer (score 0):

There is error in this line -> `if(now - publishTimeInMilli) > CLOSE_APP)`. It should be `if((now - publishTimeInMilli) > CLOSE_APP)`